React component library is not bundling correctly
I'm creating a React component library with only JSX files. While the local build process successfully bundles the modules into the dist folder, the dist folder is missing when I install the library in my React app. I've tried various build tools like Vite, Microbundle, and Esbuild, but none seem to resolve this issue.
here are my configurations:
package.json
  ...
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.modern.js",
  "umd:main": "dist/index.umd.js",
  "unpkg": "dist/index.umd.js",
  "source": "src/index.ts",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    "./package.json": "./package.json",
    ".": {
      "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
      "import": "./dist/index.modern.js",
      "require": "./dist/index.js"
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf dist && node esbuild.js && tsc"
  },
  ...

tsconfig.json
{
  "include": ["src"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "jsx": "react",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "strict": true,
  }
}


esbuild.js settings:
const esbuild = require('esbuild');
const { nodeExternalsPlugin } = require('esbuild-node-externals');
esbuild
  .build({
    entryPoints: ['./src/index.ts'],
    outfile: 'dist/index.js',
    bundle: true,
    minify: true,
    treeShaking: true,
    platform: 'node',
    format: 'cjs',
    target: 'node14',
    plugins: [nodeExternalsPlugin()],
  })
  .catch(() => process.exit(1));


**Note: Removing dist folder form .gitingore seems to be working, but I don't see packages on github with build files, how does this work?

How exactly do you install the library in your React app?

I tried locally and then pushed it to github and tried to install, but still same results
